# Replace entire column in text file unix

Tags: unix

Is there a simple unix command like `awk` that will let me replace an entire column with the same string every line. Right now, column 8 of a text file has a random single digit number in it. I need to replace this on every line with an atomic element symbol (one or two characters). It will be the same character for the entire file.

Hence:

```
1 2 3 a b c x 4

1 2 3 a b c x 7

1 2 3 a b c x 2
```

should be

```
1 2 3 a b c x U

1 2 3 a b c x U

1 2 3 a b c x U
```

but with a few thousand lines.

Answer (score 0):

@try:

```
awk '{$NF="U";print}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{sub(/.*/,"U",$NF);print}'   Input_file
```

Simply changing the last field of each line to "U" and then printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Perl works:

`perl -alne "$F[7]= 'U'; print (join ' ', @F) ;" characterFile.txt > characterFile2.txt`

puts your results in characterFile2.txt so you can keep your original file.

This actually changes the 8th column (assuming delimitation by spaces), so you can have more than 8 columns and it will only change the 8th.  Probably barf if you have less than 8 columns....

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/x ./,"x U")}1' file
1 2 3 a b c x U

1 2 3 a b c x U

1 2 3 a b c x U
```

Answer (score 0):

When column 7 is the last column:

```
sed 's/.$/U/' inputfile
```

Redirect to a tmp file and move it when your `sed`doesn't support the `-i`flag:

```
sed -i 's/.$/U/' inputfile
```